# CORS Header allow cross origin not working for google fonts

Tags: .htaccess, cors

Here I have some code in my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"

# `mod_headers` cannot match based on the content-type, however,
# the `X-UA-Compatible` response header should be send only for
# HTML documents and not for the other resources.

<FilesMatch "\.(appcache|atom|bbaw|bmp|crx|css|cur|eot|f4[abpv]|flv|geojson|gif|htc|ico|jpe? 
g|js|json(ld)?|m4[av]|manifest|map|mp4|oex|og[agv]|opus|otf|pdf|png|rdf|rss|safariextz|svgz? 
|swf|topojson|tt[cf]|txt|vcard|vcf|vtt|webapp|web[mp]|webmanifest|woff2?|xloc|xml|xpi)$">
 Header unset X-UA-Compatible
</FilesMatch>

</IfModule>
```

on the first line i have the Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" and it does not seem to be working for any browser except for chrome. I tried using this in my root .htaccess file as well as .htaccess file in app folder. Is there something i am doing wrong? Also I should add that I am using a css @font-face for these google fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a simple module for this or extend one you have previously made.

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Vendor_Module', __DIR__);
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/csp_whitelist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="font-src">
            <values>
                <!--Google-->
                <value id="google-services" type="host">www.googleservices.com</value>
                <value id="google" type="host">*.google.com</value>
                <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```

After you have implemented this this should fix your font issues, please refer to [Magento 2 DevDocs - Content Security Policies](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/security/content-security-policies.html) for further information

Comment: Works fine. Thanks.

Comment: @DylanT glad to hear